# Reading in Python a textfile with list comprehension and covert some values in a float

Tags: python, coding-style, list-comprehension, floating

I have a text file with x, y, and Id

```
text = "c:\\text.txt"

480031, 6171223, 77-1084-A,
478578, 6170168, 77-0767-A, 
479429, 6171688, 77-1065-A, 
479526, 6190464, 79-1420-A, 
480469, 6183769, 78-2071-A,
......, ......., .........,
```

I use list comprehension to read the file in a list

```
centres = [l.split() for l in open(text, "r")]

[['480031', '6171223', '77-1084-A'],
['478578', '6170168', '77-0767-A'], 
['479429', '6171688', '77-1065-A'], 
['479526', '6190464', '79-1420-A'],
........., ........., ...........]]
```

I wish if possible to convert the x, y in float when i use the list comprehension in order to have

```
[[480031, 6171223, '77-1084-A'],
[478578, 6170168, '77-0767-A'], 
[479429, 6171688, '77-1065-A'], 
[479526, 6190464, '79-1420-A'],
........., ........., ...........]]
```

Comment: Why do you want it as a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite one step, but you can do:

```
centres = [l.split() for l in open(text, "r")]
centres = [[int(x), int(y), z] for x, y, z in centres]
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way in one line?

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-line example:

```
centres = [[int(l[0]), int(l[1]), l[2].strip()] for l in [l.split(',') for l in open(text, "r")]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's cool and all, doing it in a single line; but it's a lot more readable (understandable, maintainable) to spread it out a bit:

```
INPUT = "c:/text.txt"

def convert(line):
    row = line.split()
    return (int(row[0]), int(row[1]), row[2])

with open(INPUT) as inf:
    centres = [convert(line) for line in inf]
```